# Is there a way to set a default view on Google News?

Tags: google-news

Is there a way to set a default view on Google News? I like reading Google News' Business and Science Tech sections and I would like to make it so by default one of these pages opens. Is this possible?

Comment: This is possible now with the "sections" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Closest you can do is bookmark the section or rearrange it so that it is one of the upper most sections on the Google News home page.